# solving an ODE Dirichlet problem on a symmetric interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I need to find a solution to the Boundary Value problem $$\cases {y'' = f(x)\\ y(-1)=y(1)=0}$$
I'm unsure of where to start and how to find the solution here, since the interval appears to be symmetric... Please help?

Comment: Isn’t this just a case of taking anti-derivatives twice and then solving for the two constants? Other than that, without information about $f,$ there’s not much to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Integrating twice, we have

$$y(x)=F(x)+ax+b$$

where $F''(x)=f(x)$.

Then you simply have to solve the equations

$$0=F(1)+a+b$$

$$0=F(-1)-a+b$$

for $a$ and $b$ and you are done.

**Approach 2:**

From the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that

$$y(x)=\int_{a}^x y'(s)ds+y(a)=\int_a^x\left(\int_b^s y''(t)dt+y'(b) \right)+y(a)$$

$$=\int_a^x\left(\int_b^s f(t)dt+y'(b) \right)+y(a)$$

for real numbers $a$ and $b$. Now, by [Rolle's Theorem](https://www.britannica.com/science/Rolles-theorem) there exists $\omega\in (-1,1)$ such that $y'(\omega)=0$. Then choose $a=-1$ and $b=\omega$ to get

$$y(x)=\int_{-1}^x\left(\int_\omega^s f(t)dt+y'(\omega) \right)+y(-1)=\int_{-1}^x\left(\int_\omega^s f(t)dt \right)$$